# how to add a null field with integer?

Tags: mysql, null

I have a table which has column A and Column B, both of integer datatype. In column A, I have a **null** value, in column B, I have **300**.

*How can i add these two fields in column C?*

Comment: what value is then be added on `C`? `NULL` or `300`?

Comment: If the columns allow `Null`? *How can i add these two fields in column C?* what does that mean? Can you show us your table data please.. (small sample)

Comment: Try to improve your question description and provide some sample data what you want to do.

Comment: in sql, `NULL + 300 = NULL`

Answer (score 2):

If I've got it right:

```
update YourTable set C=IFNULL(A,0)+IFNULL(B,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add an integer value with a null value, then the result will be a null value.

**Integer + Null = Null**

So, you better eliminate null value by specifying constraint **not null** in the table alteration query to be able to perform the addition operation. Otherwise, the default value in the column will be null and you will not be able to perform any operation with that null value.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, you cannot. The purpose of `NULL` in `A` is to indicate that you don't know what `A` is. However, you could ask yourself if a default value for column `A` would make sense, and change the table accordingly.